# How to set the selected value of a drop down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `form_for @company` and I create a drop down list with a constant:

```
NOTIFY = [['Never', 'never'],['End Of The Day', 'end_of_day']]

<%= f.select(:notify, NOTIFY) %>
```

How do I set the selected value of the drop down to be `@company.notify`?

Answer (score 0):

Put `@company.notify = 'never'` (or `'end_of_day'` what you want) in the controller (in `new` action) or before the select tag